# How to get last week begin date and last month begin date in c#?

Tags: c#

i want to retrieve records based on last week and last month in c#.For last week i want records from sunday to saturday.For last month i want to get last month begin date to fetch all the records till end of that month.

i should not fetch last six days records for last week instead i want to find last sunday date from current week(sunday) begin date.

i found solution for finding last month first and last day---->

```
 var first = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1).AddMonths(-1);
                    var last = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1).AddDays(-1);
```

finding last week----->

```
DateTime _currDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
                    DateTime _currentDate;
                    DateTime _lastWeekStartDate;
                    _currentDate = _currDateTime.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Sunday);
                    _lastWeekStartDate = _currentDate.AddDays(-1);
                    tempfromdate = _lastWeekStartDate.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Sunday);
                    temptodate = tempfromdate.EndOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Saturday);
```

Comment: How do you define week? Different cultures define it differently. In particular the first day of the week varies.

Answer (score 5):

This is at least a way of doing it

```
DateTime lastWeekFirstDay = DateTime.Now.AddDays( - 6 - (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek);
DateTime lastMonthFirstDay = DateTime.Now.AddMonths( -1 ).AddDays( 1 - DateTime.Now.Day);
```

Replace the 6 with 7 in the first line of code if Sunday is the first day of the week in your culture. 6 assumes Monday is the first day of the week.

**EDIT**

Added a variant of the month variant that is probably a bit more readable:

```
DateTime lastMonthFirstDay = new DateTime( DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddMonths(-1);
```

Comment: Logic for last Month first day and last day.Last Month logic working.Thanks dudes